# flex 3 coldfusion 10 issue

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have a Flex 3 application that uses a WebService and loadWSDL() to call a ColdFusion function with a returntpe of query.  The Flex 3 application stores the return data in a ArrayCollection.  The problem is Flex parses the data fine on ColdFusion 8 but not 10.  I do see the data being returned when ran under ColdFusion 10 but it does look like the format is a little different.  I am wondering if maybe it is a SOAP 1.1 versus 1.2 issue possibly. Does anyone have anything in mind that may be causing this?

Comment: What is the problem.  You say that Flex parses the data incorrectly.  How do you know?  Are you receiving errors?  If so, what are the errors?  ( As a point of commentary; why on earth did someone use Flex with ColdFusion and choose a SOAP Web service over the built in AMF gateway? )

Comment: I agree, I would use remoteObjects

Comment: Basically the problem is this Flex 3 app worked using ColdFusion 8 but once the cfc's were move to ColdFusion 10 it no longer worked.  I know data is coming back because I can see the return data in Fiddler.  There are no errors either.  This is a legacy app which I can not re-write using a AMF gateway.  I am hoping maybe there is a setting that I can put in my Application.cfc to have it return the object like ColdFusion 8.

Comment: I figured it out.  Adding <cfset this.wssettings.version.consume = "1">  in my Application.cfc forces it to use Axis1 web services or SOAP 1.1 format which Coldfusion 8 supports.

Comment: Since you solved your issue; please post that as a formal answer and select it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line

```
<cfset this.wssettings.version.consume = "1">
```

to your Application.cfc will force Coldfusion 10 to use Axis1 web services and the SOAP 1.1 format which Flex 3 supports.  The Application.cfc file is placed in your applications root directory.